# iOS: How do I transfer a mp3 from Google Drive to iBooks?

Tags: ios, books, mp3, google-apps, audiobook

I have an mp3 audiobook on Google Drive that I want to listen to in iBooks on my iPhone. How can I transfer/copy/open that file from the Google Drive app on the iBooks app?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this and works for me: https://www.guidingtech.com/31994/audiobooks-iphone-ipad/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Answers should be self-contained so others can find them by using the search feature.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review